# close hole in rounded shape

Tags: modeling

I have a very easy (maybe silly) question, but I cant get it done....

How can I close hole like above (or bigger) mantaining the round shape?

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ***Grid Fill*** option. Select the edge loop around the hole, then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *Grid Fill*. Play with its settings in a *Tool Shelf's* operator panel (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: You are the men @Paul Gonet! Thank you! How do you do this cool gif?

Comment: go here to see how to create gifs: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers